# Terraria NPC house

Tags: terraria

So I built a house and even built one from a tutorial and it says Jake would like to settle down anyway[image]

So I remade his house now and does this mean my house is valid
and I travelled a bit and checked for any biome in the way and there is none, does this mean anything or should I ignore this?

[image]

Comment: I haven't played the tablet version, but generally you have to wait a while for NPC's to move in. Have you tried leaving the area for a while? (e.g. walking to the other side of the map)

Comment: I did that before tearing his house down and remaking it. Gonna try that with his new house

Comment: The banner in the house means he's now living there. I think you've answered your own question :)

Answer (score 4):

According to the wiki page on [the guide](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide) Barney is not among the names he has. This means that there is another NPC that wants to move in. It would probably be a good idea to build another house for that NPC unless you don't want him for some reason. Barney is probably [the merchant](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Merchant) who is quite useful.

As a side note, your leftmost building in the first screenshot is not a valid house, but it does not look like it is intended to be one either.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest waiting or taking a stroll to the other side of the map and see if that fixes the problem. If not then here's a list of possible reasons the Guide isn't moving in.

1. Your close to the corruption or crimson. Just try moving away from the infectious red/purple grass to some normal green grass.
2. Make sure the house is at least 8x8 and has all the necessities for a house such as a table, chair, light source and door. 8x8 is the optimal size for a room that doesn't take up much space, but lets npcs move in
3. Npcs usually wont move into houses during night or when your inside the room you have built for them. Either wait for day or take a jog across the map.
4. Also make sure no other npc is inside the house. Two npcs can't move in the same house together.

I hope this helped.

Comment: I guess I was a tad bit late for this question, you answered it yourself. Good luck with the rest of the game! =D