# Why is my house not valid?

Tags: terraria

My house that is made out of meteorite is not being counted as a valid housing, what's the reason for this?

[image]

Comment: [This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/238567/terraria-npc-house) is probably not a duplicate, but definitely related.

Comment: What does the tooltip say when you hover over the house and click it?

Comment: Is it close to the crimson or corruption? NPC's won't move in if it is.

Comment: [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22408/how-do-i-build-a-house-for-my-npcs) is our go-to for housing questions.

Comment: On the bottom of your screen there - Are those [Purple (Corrupted) Ice blocks](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ice_Blocks)?

Comment: Isn’t meteorite invalid? Or am I just dumb?

Comment: @brododragon Meteorite bricks, walls and furniture are perfectly valid for housing. And no, you're not dumb :) It's ok to question stuff sometimes (That's what this site is for, right?)

Answer (score 9):

[image]

On the bottom of your screen there (I highlighted it in the above screenshot), it looks like you have a lot of purple (corrupted) ice blocks. A house that has too much corruption (or crimson) close by will become unhabitable.

You should either move the house away from those blocks, or remove them from near your base.

Comment: Nice catch, did not see that untill you pointed it out